# Is there a way to search in Visual Studio and return only matches which are called from a function/method of interest?

Tags: visual-studio

Suppose I have the following psuedo-code:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        SomeMethod() 
        { 
            print("hello")
        }

        MainMethod()
        {
            SomeMethod()
        }

        AnotherMethod()
        {
            print("hello")
        }
    }
```

In this example, suppose I want to find a reference with my point of interest at `MainMethod`.

I search for `print("hello")`

In this example, we would see a result like:

`MainMethod.SomeMethod --> print("hello")`

In other words, in this example, we don't care about `AnotherMethod` - it would only pollute our find results.

Is there a Visual Studio feature or extension which provides this capability?

In the real world, there could be dozens or hundreds of results, if we could drill down by a particular initial method we care about to filter the result set, this would be extremely useful.

Thanks.